# Foreach está retornando apenas um registro

Tags: php, loop

Estou com um problema com meu código. Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php
require('class/habeo.class.php');
$Habeo->DuplicateRegister('contatos', array('id'=>'1', 'id'=>'6'));
?>
```

Essa classe duplica os registros que tenho no banco de dados. Ele conta quantos elementos tem no array e faz um loop para duplicar as **id** informadas. A classe que duplica é a seguinte:

```
<?php
function($de, $condicao){   
    foreach($condicao as $campo=>$value){
        $SQL = mysql_query('INSERT INTO {$de} ({$Columns}) 
                                  SELECT {$Columns} FROM {$de} 
                                  WHERE {$campo}='{$value}');
    }
}
?>
```

O problema é que ele faz um loop só com 1, sendo que existem 2 registros no array.

Eu visualizei que o erro é porque os indices do array é o mesmo nome **id** e por isso estão retornando somente 1, agora quando mudo o nome ele retorna 2.

Comment: Esse array tem 2 itens **array('id'=>'1', 'id'=>'6');** e quando eu faço o loop com o foreach ele me retorna apenas o último item. Caso eu mude 1 elemente para outro nome, ele retorna 2 itens no loop.

Comment: É normal este comportamento, se vc especifica várias vezes a mesma chave num array, somente a última vale.

Comment: como resolvo esse problema, pois vou fazer a duplicação de vários registros e irei informar "quais" pelo **id** então terei que colocar **id=>XXX** várias vezes.

Comment: Provavelmente vai ter que usar outra biblioteca ou função, pois qualquer coisa baseada em array associativa vai ter o mesmo problema.

Comment: @Bacco saberia alguma função para usar no lugar do array() ?

Comment: Não é só trocar o array, tem que repensar o código todo do loop. Eu provavelmente usaria duas arrays, desta forma: `novaFuncao( $tabela, Array( campo1, campo2 ...), Array( valor1, valor2...)` e um `for ( count( ... ) ){ ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Como disse o Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23627/foreach-est%c3%a1-retornando-apenas-um-registro/23630#comment43578_23627), você não pode ter mais de uma chave com o mesmo nome numa array. Mas você pode chamar sua função várias vezes:

```
$Habeo->DuplicateRegister('contatos', array('id'=>'1'));
$Habeo->DuplicateRegister('contatos', array('id'=>'6'));
```

Se os IDs estiverem em outra array, faça um loop por fora:

```
$ids = array(1, 6);
foreach($ids as $id) {
    $Habeo->DuplicateRegister('contatos', array('id'=>$id));
}
```

Comment: Obrigado a você e o @Bacco

Comment: Talvez seja mais eficiente fazer como o Bacco sugeriu (passar uma array de campos e outra de valores), mas esta é uma solução rápida (de escrever).

Answer (score 3):

Uma opção é usar uma matriz:

```php
array( array("id"=>1), array("id"=>2) )
```

E o loop ficaria assim:

```php
foreach ($lista as $item) {
    $item["id"];
}
```